# MySQL JSON Search Extract

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, database, extract

I'm currently inputting JSON objects to a MySQL Database and then want to run queries on them. So what I have is a table as below:

```
subjects                                                |
---------------------------------------------------------
|{
|"subjects": [{
|  "subject":"English Language & Literature",
|  "ageRange":["12-18"],
|  "examlevel":["13+","gcse","as-level","a-level"],
|  "examboard":["aqa","edexcel","ocr","wjec"]
|},
|{
|  "subject":"Creative Writing",
|  "ageRange":["8-18"],                                     | Row 1
|  "examlevel":null,
|  "examboard":null
|},
|{
|  "subject":"Media Studies",
|  "ageRange":["14-18"],
|  "examlevel":["gcse","as-level","a-level"],
|  "examboard":["aqa","edexcel","ocr","wjec"]
|}]
|}
---------------------------------------------------------
```

In a MySQL query I ran

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(subjects, '$."subjects"') FROM `table_name`
```

And I get this in response

```
[{"subject": "English Language & Literature", "age...
```

To get the subject name I did the following...

```
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(subjects, '$."subjects[*]."subject"') FROM `table_name`
```

This Returns

```
["English Language & Literature", "Creative Writin...
```

I then this to try and run a search query against the JSON Extract

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(subjects, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(subjects, 'all', '{Search Query i.e "E"}', NULL, '$."subjects"[*]."subject"'))) FROM `table_name`
```

This ^^ Returns NULL

I want to query this further. So I want to end up extracting the subject name from each JSON object for each of the subjects in this Object group. Effectively, when you search for a subject, it searches the subject name for each subject field in each JSON Object for every row to get the results to relate to the search query.

I've had a look at the MySQL Docs and not very helpful... - Now that I have pulled the Extracted JSON data, how can I run a search against them? And then only retrieve the ones that match that search query.

Comment: Show definite `{Search Query i.e "E"}` value as it is inserted into the query. I think that you add dquotes to the string literal simply... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d313262b9be61f792d8e2616e5279460

Comment: From the other side you want "select a value by the path where definite value is posessed" - i.e. you want to find the value of the criteria which you use for searching.. it is slightly strange.

Comment: @Akina That's great that worked! Thanks for that. So... I have a database full of JSON values and like such above and basically, on the site, for the global search, when one searches inputs text, it finds rows which contain the subject name in JSON and fetches the first 4 and then displays then grabs the a single column to the left and displays that. Make sense? Up for suggestions if there's a better way in mind... Did have a look at using Generated Columns but didn't suit what we are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the comments here are the answers I found to work.

This will fetch the columns when the string entered, exactly matches what you are looking for.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(subjects, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(subjects,'all','Creative Writing', NULL, '$."subjects"[*]."subject"'))) FROM `table_name`
```

--

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(subjects, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(LOWER(subjects),'all',LOWER('%eng%'), NULL, '$."subjects"[*]."subject"'))) FROM `table_name`
```

This will fetch the columns with a string that contains the characters 'eng' and isn't case sensitive so will get all matching rows.

--